# How to use components in listview and get the list item click and also the component click?

Tags: java, android, listview, listitem

I need to add a component like checkbox in listview with listitem.
I have added the component using layout inflator.
Now the problem is i can't get onitemclick for listitems.
How to have both on list item click and other list item component click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for click on listview use this

```
lv.setClickable(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    /* write you handling code like...
    String st = "sdcard/";
    File f = new File(st+o.toString());
    // do whatever u want to do with 'f' File object
    */  
  }
});
```